# DPKG returns error when generating boot image

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I have been searching for assistance on the following problem for a while with no results.

I am trying to update/upgrade ubuntu using apt-get.

Specifically I am running the following commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I have tried removing my sources file like so

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I have also tried to reset my sources using the following tool.

```
$ sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Despite this I continue to get the following error when updating.

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 ifupdown
 cups-browsed
 libvirt-bin
 network-manager
 network-manager-gnome
 software-properties-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: What did you do to arrive at this point ? My guess is your system is fairly broken and you are deleting system files ? Why ? What other system files did you delete or edit ? Did you add a repo ? Mix repos ?

Comment: Also please add more information from dpkg.

Comment: I didn't delete any system files, I ended up deciding to blow it up and re install.